# Integrating Factor Initial Value Problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve for the initial value with the given equation:

$xy'+y = e^{\sin x}\cos x$ for y$\left(π\right)$ = 1

I have tried to isolate the $y'$ by multiplying the whole equation by $\frac 1x$ and I got:

$y' + \frac 1x$$y= \frac 1x$$e^{\sin x}\cos x$

I thus got my integrating factor as:

> $I\left(x\right)$= $e^{∫ \frac 1x}$
>
> = $e^{\log x}$
>
> = x

I'm not really sure how do I continue from here though.

Comment: The left hand is $\frac d{dx} xy$.

Answer (score 2):

For a differential equation of the form, $$y'+{\rm P}(x) \cdot y = {\rm Q}(x)$$ Once you've got Integrating Factor, the solution is given by $$y \cdot {\rm (IF)} = \int {\rm Q}(x) \cdot {\rm ( IF)} {\rm d}x + {\rm C}$$

Can you continue now?

Comment: I got back to the same equation from the start after multiplying by I(x) and got d/dx (xy)= int { (e^(sinx))cosx.}

Comment: @Jenny Now you just need to integrate both the sides. Integral of LHS will be $xy$ whereas for RHS, substitute $\sin x = t$, and proceed. You'll get $$\int e^{\sin x} \cos x {\rm d} x = e^{\sin x} + {\rm C}$$ And you need to find ${\rm C} $ using initial condition $y(\pi)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
  & Notice\ that\ x{y}'+y={{\left( xy \right)}^{\prime }} \\ 
 & {{\left( xy \right)}^{\prime }}={{e}^{\sin \left( x \right)}}\cos \left( x \right)dx \\ 
 & \int{{{\left( xy \right)}^{\prime }}dx}=\int{{{e}^{\sin \left( x \right)}}\cos \left( x \right)dx}=\int{{{e}^{u}}du}={{e}^{u}}+C={{e}^{\sin \left( x \right)}}+C\quad by\ setting\ u=\sin \left( x \right) \\ 
 & hence \\ 
 & xy={{e}^{\sin \left( x \right)}}+C\quad OR\quad y=\frac{1}{x}\left( {{e}^{\sin \left( x \right)}}+C \right) \\ 
\end{align}$$